# Login bug in Mezzanine site

Tags: mezzanine

we have just recently started on a project using the mezzanine cms platform. we were trying to implement the authentication/login feature but already encountered a problem:

http://usbong.pythonanywhere.com

when you click the "Login" button (the one beside Sign Up, not the link) nothing happens when the Login Form is supposed to show. Signup works just fine but you can't log in. Once you login using other means (admin), it's the "Logout" button's turn not to work.

any help please? thank you

EDIT: it appears that *mezzanine.accounts* and django's *allauth* appear not to work well together? because when we comment out allauth in settings.py, the login works. what is the workaround for both of them to work at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

All auth supports username/password login. Any reason why you wouldn't just use that?